# ¿Como hago para que se me guarde una foto en una URL en MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, android, xampp

Las distintas formas que existen en internet no me ayudan porque yo no estoy usando HTML, me pasa que estoy desarrollando un aplicativo de inventario en el cual ya genera el codigo QR por cada articulo que se registre nuevo, ¿Que es lo que yo quiero? Bueno, cuando registra un producto ya genera el QR cierto y lo arroja en una carpeta en htdocs que yo llamo codigos_qr en formato PNG, quiero que la ruta de ese PNG lo almacene en la base de datos para cada producto individual, lo cual necesito, simplemente, registre, genere el QR y de una vez guarde la ruta del QR individualmente DE ESE producto. Mas nada. El codigo que tengo hasta ahora para generar el QR es este:

GenerarQR.php

```
<?php   

//*Conexion a base de datos *//

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contrumeca"); 

$codigosqr = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codproducto, nombre_producto, margen_utilidad, unidad_manejo, descripcion, proveedor, precio, existencia, tipo_producto, imagen, qr FROM producto ORDER BY codproducto ASC");

//Para subir la imagen *//



//*Generando el codigo QR *//
require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

$directorio = 'codigos/';

//*Si no existe la carpeta *//

if(!file_exists($directorio))
{
    mkdir($directorio);

}

$filename = $directorio.'test.png';


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($codigosqr))
{

    $filename = $directorio. 'test'.$row['nombre_producto'].'.png';

    $contenido = "Codigo de Identificación: {$row['codproducto']} Nombre: {$row['nombre_producto']}, Margen de Utilidad: {$row['margen_utilidad']}, Unidad de manejo: {$row['unidad_manejo']}, Caracteristicas: {$row['descripcion']}, Precio a la venta: {$row['precio']}, Foto: {$row['imagen']}";

    QRCode::png($contenido, $filename);

    echo '<img src ="'.$directorio.basename($filename).'"/><hr/>';

    echo $filename;   


    }

?>
```

Este es mi codigo ORIGINAL para generar QR, pero no hallo de que manera mas o menos pudiera implementarle que al agregar producto ejecute generar el QR(qeu ya lo hace) y que suba la foto al servidor localhost del QR generado de ese producto y lo almacene en la BD

Ayuda por favor?

Gracias.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. ¿Quieres mandar la imagen desde Android al servidor para guardarla en la base de datos?

Comment: No, amigo, cuando yo agrego un producto de una vez genera el codigo QR en en archivo png y la arroja en la carpeta que yo tengo en el htdocs, pero quiero que ese archivo por id de producto sea almacenado en la base de datos, esa ruta pues, eso es lo que yo quiero.

Comment: Que en el campo QR de mi tabla 'producto' este la ruta del QR por codproducto

Comment: Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y aclara mejor la pregunta porque es confuso tu planteamiento.

Comment: Ya realize los respectivos cambios, pero me interesa que la comunidad me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es guardar `$filename`? Pues lanzas una consulta `INSERT` para que te lo guarde donde lo quieras guardar.

Comment: Ya lo hice y no me funciona, si, solo el archivo quiero almacenarlo en la base de datos, en el campo QR de la tabla producto, pero claro, de manera individual, respetando el cod producto.

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu problema amigo. Además si el patrón será siempre el mismo: `$directorio. 'test'.$row['nombre_producto'].'.png'` ¿para qué quieres guardarlo, si con `nombre_producto` puedes construir la ruta de forma dinámica ¿? Lo único que justificaría eso sería que el directorio o la extensión del archivo cambie. De lo contrario, sería un dato redundante.

Comment: Amigo solo quiero que me almacene automaticamente la ruta del archivo PNG en el atributo QR de la tabla producto, mas nada;

Comment: move_uploaded_file($filename, $dir);
            $bytes=file_get_contents($filename);
            guardarQR($content,$bytes);

Comment: Ese fue el codigo que use y no me funciona.